# How can I calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}x^{2}\ln\left(\cos \left(\pi/x\right)\right) $?

Tags: calculus, limits

Does anybody know how to solve this?
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}x^{2}\ln\left(\cos\left(\pi \over x\right)\right)$$

Comment: There is nothing to "solve". You wouldn't ask someone how to "solve $1+1$". You are trying to evaluate a limit, i.e. find the value of something.

Comment: Sorry @FelixMarin changed calculate to evaluate (?)

Comment: I didn't change any thing. I just put some $\large\tt LaTeX\quad\mbox{( some \left, \right, etc... )}$. Somebody else did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $x\to\infty,\,\pi/x\to0$; so $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)\sim 1-\frac{\pi^2}{2x^2}$ and $\ln\left(1-\frac{\pi^2}{2x^2}\right)\sim \left(-\frac{\pi^2}{2x^2}\right)$ so for $x\to\infty$
$$
x^2\ln\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)\sim x^2\ln\left(1-\frac{\pi^2}{2x^2}\right)\sim x^2\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{2x^2}\right)=-\frac{\pi^2}{2}
$$

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large\cos\left(z\right) \approx 1 - {z^{2} \over 2}\quad\mbox{when}\quad z \approx 0}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  as $x \to \infty, \frac \pi x \to 0$  Use the Taylor series of $\cos$ and use that with one you know of $\log$

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\ln(\cos(\pi/x)) = \dfrac12\ln(\cos^2(\pi/x)) = \dfrac12\ln(1-\sin^2(\pi/x)) = -\dfrac12 \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin^{2k}(\pi/x)}k\right)$$
Hence,
$$x^2\ln(\cos(\pi/x)) = -\dfrac12 \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^2\dfrac{\sin^{2k}(\pi/x)}k\right)$$
Now take limit as $x\to \infty$ and use the fact that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 \sin^{2k}(\pi/x) = \begin{cases} \pi^2 & k=1\\ 0 & k>1 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
x^{2}\ln\pars{\cos\pars{\pi \over x}}
\sim
x^{2}\ln\pars{1 - {\pi^{2} \over 2x^{2}}}
\sim
x^{2}\pars{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 2x^{2}}}\quad\mbox{when}\quad\verts{x} \gg 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=1/t$. So we are interested in the limit as $t\to 0^+$ of $\ln(\cos(\pi t))/t^2$.

One round of L'Hospital's Rule brings us to 
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} -\frac{\pi}{2\cos(\pi t)} \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{t}.$$
The first part is nicely behaved near $0$. For $\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{t}$, use L'Hospital's Rule, or simpler tools.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use a change of variables $u = \frac{\pi}{x}$ and then it will be solvable by first year calculus (you do not even have to use a Taylor's series).

Answer (score 0):

An entirely different approach is to reexpess $x^2 \ln{\big(\cos{(\frac{\pi}{x})}\big)}$ as  $\ln{\big(\big(\cos{(\frac{\pi}{x}})\big)^{x^2}\big)}$.